How to update state from a sibling component in React
I have a web page with a side panel and a main panel. The main panel is a chat screen. I have the following code there.
const MainPanel = (({ chatList }) => {

  const [userChat, setUserChat] = useState('');
  const [chatArray, setChatArray] = useState([]);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Some UI login here
    postChatEntry(newMessage);
  }

  async function postChatEntry(message) {
    const request = new Request("/chat", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: message.chatEntry })
    });

    const response = await fetch(request);
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    if (jsonResponse) {
      chatArray.push(jsonResponse.reply);
      const deepCopy = [...chatArray]
      setChatArray(deepCopy);
    }
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        {chatArray.map((message) => {
           <ChatBubble chat={message} key={message.id} />
        })}
      </div>
      <form id="chatForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          placeholder='Type your message here...'
          value={userChat}
          onChange={(e) => setUserChat(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button>Post</button>
      </form>
    </section>
  )
})

Now, in my side panel, I have buttons to clear the chat and load history. When I click on these buttons, I was the chat section in the MainPanel to be updated.
In my SidePanel, I have the following.
const SidePanel = (({ setChatList }) => {

  function loadHistory(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('/history').then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => {
      const list = parseResponse(data)
      setChatList(list);
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a onClick={loadHistory}>Clear Chat</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
})

In my App (which is the parent of SidePanel and MainPanel) I have the following:
function App() {

  const [chatList, setChatList] = useState([]);

  return (
     <div className="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-dark">
       <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
          <SidePanel setChatList={setChatList} />
       </div>
       <div className="col py-3 h-100">
          <MainPanel chatList={chatList} />
       </div>
     </div>
  );
}

From the above code, I have a state (chatArray) in the main-panel that I am able to use to update the dom every time I make and API call. However, When I get a refreshed value from the side panel, I am not able to update it in the MainPanel.
I am very new to React (started learning a week back). Any suggestions will help.
I tried using the same state (chatList) which I update in the SidePanel and pass to the MainPanel through the App, instead of having a separate state (chatArray) in the MainPanel. This did not work - With this approach the values from the SidePanel and now refreshed in the MainPanel. But API responses within the MainPanel are not reflected.

Please force the component MainPanel to render on every run of the loadHistory event in the component SidePanel.
At present you have passed the chatList to MainPanel, still it does not have rendered there. It must be rendered in the component MainPanel. Not only this, whenever you click "Clear Chat", the MainPanel component must re-render with the chat history. These two functionalities can be achieved as below.
a) Use key as below to force to render MainPanel on every click of "Clear Chat". To learn more about this, please see the documentation Resetting state with a key
  <div className="col py-3 h-100">
    <MainPanel key={Math.random()} chatList={chatList} />
  </div>

b) Please add a separate rendering logic in MainPanel exclusively for chatList as below.
{chatArray.length == 0 &&
  chatList.map((message, i) => (
    <Fragment key={i}>
      <label>{message}</label>
      <br />
    </Fragment>
  ))}

A full listing of modified code with test results
Please note the API calls and the Components for which the source has not been included in the question have been substituted appropriately
for the completeness of a working version to demo here.
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [chatList, setChatList] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-dark">
      <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
        <SidePanel setChatList={setChatList} />
      </div>
      <div className="col py-3 h-100">
        <MainPanel key={Math.random()} chatList={chatList} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const MainPanel = ({ chatList }) => {
  const [userChat, setUserChat] = useState('');
  const [chatArray, setChatArray] = useState([]);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Some UI login here
    //    postChatEntry(newMessage); // commented for the MRE
    postChatEntry(userChat); // added for the MRE
  }

  async function postChatEntry(message) {
    // const request = new Request('/chat', {
    //   method: 'POST',
    //   body: JSON.stringify({ message: message.chatEntry }),
    // });

    // const response = await fetch(request);
    // const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    // if (jsonResponse) {
    //chatArray.push(jsonResponse.reply); //
    const deepCopy = [...chatArray, message];
    setChatArray(deepCopy);
    setUserChat('');
    // }
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        {chatArray.length == 0 &&
          chatList.map((message, i) => (
            <Fragment key={i}>
              <label>{message}</label>
              <br />
            </Fragment>
          ))}
        {chatArray.map((message, i) => (
          <Fragment key={i}>
            <label>{message}</label>
            <br />
          </Fragment>
        ))}
      </div>
      <form id="chatForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          placeholder="Type your message here..."
          value={userChat}
          onChange={(e) => setUserChat(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
        <button>Post</button>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
};

const SidePanel = ({ setChatList }) => {
  function loadHistory(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // fetch('/history')
    //   .then((res) => res.json())
    //   .then((data) => {
    //     const list = parseResponse(data);
    //     setChatList(list);
    //   });
    setChatList(['chat-1', 'chat-2', 'chat-3']);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a onClick={loadHistory}>Clear Chat</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

Test results
On loading the App

On a new Chat

After loading from Chat history


This works. Thanks!
